# How to make the MaskedTextBox only accept HEX value?

Tags: .net, controls

I need a control that only accept HEX value in the following format:

**xxxx-xxxx**    and   x is in 0-9, a-f, A-F

So I add a MaskedTextBox and try to edit its **Mask** property, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new class is need to verify if the value input is valid and the class type should be set as MaskedTextBox1's ValidatingType property, as following:

```
public class HexValidator
{
. . .

// the following function is needed to used to verify the input
public static HexValidator Parse(string s)
{
 // remove any spaces
            s = s.Replace(" ", "");

            string[] strParts = s.Split('-');
            int nValue;

            foreach (string part in strParts)
            {
                bool result = int.TryParse(part, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, null, out nValue);
                if (false == result)
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The provided string {0} is not a valid subnet ID.", s));
            }

            return new SubnetID(strParts[0], strParts[1]);
}
}

/// set as following to associate them
maskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = typeof(HexValidator);

// in  the validationcomplete event, you could judge if the input is valid
private void maskedTextBox1_TypeValidationCompleted(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.IsValidInput)
            {
                //AppendLog("Type validation succeeded.  Message: " + e.Message);                
            }
            else
            {
                toolTip1.Show(e.Message, maskedTextBox1, maskedTextBox1.Location, 5000);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this out of the box with a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx). If you take a look at the allowed masking elements detailed at [the documentation for the `Mask` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx), you'll see that there is no way that you can enforce only hexadecimal input.

You can use a [`NumericUpDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) and set its [`Hexadecimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.hexadecimal.aspx) property to `true`, though.