# Binary numbers only TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to validate the input of a TextBox to be a binary number.

I know I can do this with RegEx but I wanted a more 'inmediate' validation, like allowing just 1's and 0's to be entered.

I thought of using MaskedTextBox but I don't know how to just allow those two characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement the KeyPress event.  Set e.Handled = true if you don't like the key:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        // Allow backspace, 0 and 1
        e.Handled = !("\b01".Contains(e.KeyChar));
    }
```

Comment: +1 I don't like `MaskedTextBox`, where users can't copy-paste. Btw why not just `e.Handle = !("01".Contains(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8)`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of getting it out of the box with [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558609/how-to-make-the-maskedtextbox-only-accept-hex-value/2559116#2559116) shows you a way of achieving this (just adapt the code to parse only 0s and 1s):

[How to make the MaskedTextBox only accept HEX value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558609/how-to-make-the-maskedtextbox-only-accept-hex-value)