# How to only allow long series of hex byte entries into textbox by user only?

Tags: c#

I've done some googling and found this relevant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558609/how-to-make-the-maskedtextbox-only-accept-hex-value) but its only for masktextbox how do I do it for textbox instead?

For instance, 24 hex byte entries xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx where x is 0-9, a-f ,A-F.

After which, for every group of 2 hex value is converted to its decimal equivalent to be displayed into another textbox? How to do that?

Comment: You could use the `TextChanged` event and check each time the user enters something into the `Textbox` whether it has the format that you expect, and if not notify him with a `MessageBox`. Do you have a button for the end conversion into decimal?

Comment: I do not want to resort to massageBox to notify the user, I want to only allow hex entry into the textbox then it can be converted to its decimal equivalent.

Comment: then just delete the wrong strings that don't fit your format.

Comment: Conversion: `anotherTextBox.Text = String.Join(" ", hexTextBox.Text.Split(' ').Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item, 16)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but it seems to work.

Add a `TextChanged` and a `KeyPress` handler for your text box as follows (this code assumes that the text box is called `textBox1` - obviously you should substitute your own):

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int caret = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    bool atEnd = caret == textBox1.TextLength;
    textBox1.Text = sanitiseText(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    textBox1.SelectionStart = atEnd ? textBox1.TextLength : caret;
}

void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isHexDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b')
        e.Handled = true;
}

string sanitiseText(string text)
{
    char[] result = new char[text.Length*2];

    int n = 0;

    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if ((n%3) == 2)
            result[n++] = ' ';

        if (isHexDigit(c))
            result[n++] = c;
    }

    return new string(result, 0,  n);
}

bool isHexDigit(char c)
{
    return "0123456789abcdef".Contains(char.ToLower(c));
}
```

As for your second question: That's a different question and therefore you should post a separate question for it.

Comment: Hi for the second question the link is here wonder do you know the solutions for it? Thank You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382165/how-to-set-hex-entry-ranges-for-different-segments-in-a-data-message