# How to dynamically adjust the length of a message based on the second byte entry from a string of byte entries?

Tags: c#

Assuming my **second byte** in hex is a representation of the message length, how can I dynamically adjust the length of the message the user can key into the textbox based on the hex value of the second byte?

Message Byte entries: xx **xx** xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx ..... where x is 0-9, a-f.

The code below was used as a sort of my goal keeper to allow only hex entry into the textbox but I want to further enhance the code below with additional function mention above? Sorry if I couldn't explain it clearly enough due to my inadequate English command. Thanks

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int caret = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    bool atEnd = caret == textBox1.TextLength;
    textBox1.Text = sanitiseText(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
    textBox1.SelectionStart = atEnd ? textBox1.TextLength : caret;
}

void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isHexDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b')
        e.Handled = true;
}

string sanitiseText(string text)
{
    char[] result = new char[text.Length*2];

    int n = 0;

    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if ((n%3) == 2)
            result[n++] = ' ';

        if (isHexDigit(c))
            result[n++] = c;
    }

    return new string(result, 0,  n);
}

bool isHexDigit(char c)
{
    return "0123456789abcdef".Contains(char.ToLower(c));
}
```

Comment: From a UX pov, I wouldn't. Restricting text fields can make operations like copy and paste very frustrating. Better to validate the data and indicate good or bad by means of colour or a tick/cross. You really need to tell us what you've tried already and also to tag your question such that we don't have to guess what kind of textbox you're talking about.

Comment: What is this "message packet" that the question title talks about but the body of the question makes no mention of?

Comment: Show us your data recieived event handler.

Comment: From what I understand,  your message byte entry is the input to the textbox.

Comment: Ya the message byte is input into a textbox, but the message length could defer from message A,B or C, etc, so the second byte placement in hex of the message: xx xx xx xx xx... signifies the amount of byte the user can input into the textbox? But how can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, have a method to convert the hex to dec. Then on your data recieived event,  convert the second byte of your packet to decimal and set the MaxLenght property of the textbox equal to the size of the second byte. If you are not using events, then you can do it immediately after reading the data.

Comment: Erm, then can I see an example snippet of the code of how you will do it in codes? Because rather lost with your explanation and new to c#..