# Validating characters in KeyPress event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a form with MaskedTextBoxField where I would like to enable adding only hexadecimal values. Length of the hexadecimal value is fixed to 16 characters, first six digits are always the same, and there is a dash after every two characters.

I have set Mask property on this field to "\0\0-15-4F-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA" to allow only alphanumerics. But this way, I am able to enter all letters, not only "a-f" and "A-F".

In KeyPress event is following code:

```
char c = e.KeyChar;
if (('G' <= c && c <= 'Z') || ('g' <= c && c <= 'z'))
{
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

When I run this code, application gets to this part, but even then, characters 'G-Z' and 'g-z' are still entered in MaskedTextBox.
How can I prevent this characters being accepted in this MaskedTextBox?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558609/how-to-make-the-maskedtextbox-only-accept-hex-value

Answer (score -1):

use **keycode** insted of **keychar** so you can essaly handle this code

**e.keycode;**